# How to select values consisting of numerals only?

Tags: postgresql, string-searching

I have a column like this:

```
WW0476091
YA0457514
547856232
856987452
254785W11
```

I want to get the values that contain numerals only (decimal digits from 0 to 9). For the example above, I want only these records to be printed:

```
547856232
856987452
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I removed the tags for `sql-server` and `mysql` as you stated previously that you  are using Postgres. Please **only** add tags for the DBMS you are actually using

Comment: `where the_column in ('547856232', '856987452')`?

Comment: i have 50 lakhs records...  i have to get a count of ones that are only numeric and avoid alphanumerics

Comment: Numeric == only digits? no minus, decimal point, leading/trailing spaces, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column ~ '^[0-9]+$';
```

[Related question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975257)

Comment: thank you.. work now :)